# JAR unresponsive with Windows Explorer hyperlink?

Tags: java, jar, hyperlink, actionlistener, windows-explorer

I have a GUI application successfully packaged inside a JAR file that runs fine when I navigate to it through Windows Explorer (this is Windows 7) and actually double-click the file. However, when I try to access the JAR through a hyperlink (G:\...\file.jar), the application still opens, but it is unresponsive. Is something wrong with the action listener, perhaps, or would this be a Windows issue? I don't understand why this might be occuring or how to troubleshoot it, because it works fine in all other conditions...

Answer (score -1):

This is more of a superuser question but you could try setting the working directory of the link to be the same as the one where the jar is. It may need to retrieve some resources and it may be doing it so by using relative paths.